# searchbox in codeigniter giving blank data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model, controller

i have a simple searchbox in codeigniter, the controller is like below:

```
function searchtrack() {
    $this->load->model('excel_import_model');
    if(isset($_POST['submittrack'])) {
        $awb=$this->input->post('awb');
        $data['slt']= $this->excel_import_model->searchtrack($awb);
        $this->load->view("searchtrack",$data);
    }
}
}
```

the model is like below:

```
public function searchtrack($awbno) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where("awb", $awbno);
    $this->db->from('consignments');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();
    return $result;
}
```

and finally the display view:

```
<?php
  foreach($slt as $val){ echo $val->id; }
?>
```

however this not giving me any values, the post input is getting passed to the controller and the database column and all is fine, can anyone please tell me what is wrong in here thanks in advance

Comment: Good to see new users picking up on the community guidelines. Your questions was formulated perfectly. Looking at your code it should indeed return the correct data. But, try to check all variable names again. Also, you're pushing data into a variable called $data, which is an array but hasn't been declared yet. Try to var_dump($slt) in your view and see what that returns. After that, try to log_message( 'error', $result->countAllResults() ) in your model to see if the query returns any results.

Comment: My bad, I now see you're using the $this->db query style. In that case, try to use log_message('error', $this->db->count_all_results() ) to get more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your model, replace "where" with "[like](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-similar-data)". "Where" look for specific data where "like" look for similar data.

```
public function searchtrack($awbno) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->like("awb", $awbno, 'both');
    $this->db->from('consignments');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();
    return $result;
}
```

To control where the wildcard (%) placing in "like" method, a third parameter is used.

```
$this->db->like('awb', $awbno, 'before');    // Produces: WHERE `title` LIKE '%match' ESCAPE '!'
$this->db->like('awb', $awbno, 'after');     // Produces: WHERE `title` LIKE 'match%' ESCAPE '!'
$this->db->like('awb', $awbno, 'none');      // Produces: WHERE `title` LIKE 'match' ESCAPE '!'
$this->db->like('awb', $awbno, 'both');      // Produces: WHERE `title` LIKE '%match%' ESCAPE '!'
```

Comment: Maybe you could add some explanation of the third parameter in like? Great answer by the way.